# Raw presentation of angular js page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a single page application done in AngularJs.

when I navigate to the main page of my application (on heroku server), for a split second I see all the pictures and text in a raw state in the top left side of the browser like so:

[image]

after that the application is uploading correctly like so:

[image]

this is pretty ugly so I want to put a spinner of loading until the app is loaded.

now - here is my question - what causing this delay and raw presentation of the elements is: 1. the page controller? or 2. the loading of the entire app by the $routeProvider? I am reminding you that this is a single page app meaning all the data should load in advance.

I am asking because I tried to control the state of the app using variable inside of my run of the route provider and it didn't help:

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl : 'components/login/loginView.html',
      controller  : 'loginController'
    }) 
    .when('/chat', {
      templateUrl : 'components/chat/chatView.html',
      controller  : 'chatController'
    });
  }).run(function ($rootScope) {

    // App is loading, so set isAppLoading to true and start a timer
    console.log($rootScope);
    $rootScope.isAppLoading = true;

  });;
```

so my idea is that option 1 is correct. the what causing the problem is the controler of the page the routeProvider trying to present, and not the routeProvider loading time itself...

is that true?

hope I've managed to explaining the problem...

Thanks

Comment: So you just want to know what this happens ?

Comment: I want to know where to place my varible of the isFinishedLoading - inside the route provider like in the example I put, or inside the controller of the page I am trying to load

Comment: Inside the controller

Comment: Or you can just try both and see the results..

Comment: If you do not load data from your server, the page should be displayed at an imperceptible speed for a human... I think the problem is elsewhere

Comment: I do load data from a server. I put my code on small-talkz.herokuapp.com, this doesnt happen on localhost

Comment: could this be really a css loading time problem?

Comment: If you load angular asynchronously or you have the script include at the and of your body, It is possible you see the raw {{...}} bindings before angular can kick in. You can use ngBind  for bindings or try ngCloak. See this page for more details https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 2):

You can show loader until page is loading and hide other content while loading.

Put this css in `head`

```
body.loading > * {
   display: none;
}

body.loading > .loader {
   display: block !important;
}

body > .loader {
    display: none !important;
}
```

And add a class to `body` tag by default

```
<body class="loading" ..>
   <div class="loader">Loader Goes Here</div>
   <!-- Rest of your HTML content goes here -->
</body>
```

And you can then listen to state change events on `$rootScope`. Something like this.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
       $('body').removeClass('loading');
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
       $('body').addClass('loading');
    });
});
```